# Kotlin not configured - Kotlin 1.5.21 on IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 with openjdk 16.0.1

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Since I upgraded to Kotlin 1.5.21 I get this error:

```
Kotlin not configured
```

When compiling in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Ultimate Edition) with OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24) with Kotlin 1.5.21 & Gradle 7.1.1.

I get 114 errors on all of my Kotlin code now.

Run:

```
File | Invalidate Caches...
```

&

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/
```

I can compile & build from Gradle:

```
gradle build clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 4s
16 actionable tasks: 14 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

and create my EAR:

```
gradle MyEAR

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
```

but not with IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Ultimate Edition).

Comment: Please try lowering the Kotlin plugin. I checked on this compatibility matrix and seems like it still might not support the latest plugin 1.5.0. They have tested till 1.4.31
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: TIA. Perfect answerer.

Comment: I added it as the answer. You can accept it as the answer for the question for helping other people coming across similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

Please try lowering the Kotlin plugin. I checked on this compatibility matrix and seems like it still might not support the latest plugin `1.5.0`. They have tested till `1.4.31`

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: OMG my savor! Why the hack kotlin team don't test its compatibility before release lol

Comment: You are welcome. I guess many of us have the same questions. Rushing to release features without compatibility testing should be declared a crime.

Comment: I think Gradle `7.0.0` also having compatibility issue. 
I already update my Android Studio to `Arctic Fox` with Kotlin `1.5.0`, Gradle `4.2.2`. These configuration works perfectly.